# How do I remove duplicated strings in an array of strings?

Tags: java, string

```
public static String[] dictionary(String s){
    int count=0;
    String[] ans = sentence(s);
    int size = ans.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < ans.length; j++) {
            if (ans[i].compareTo(ans[j]) > 0) {
                String temp = ans[i];
                ans[i] = ans[j];
                ans[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ans.length; i++) {
        ans[i] = [i].to lowerCase);
    }

    return ans;
}
```

I have to find duplicated strings and remove them from an array of strings that are sorted lexicographically

Comment: use a Set for example `Set<String> nonDuplicate = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrayas.asList(sentence(s)));`

Comment: What's your question? Does this code work or not?

Comment: My questions is what is how I remove duplicated string in an array of strings

Comment: This seems to be a learning exercise so using a set is probably not the way to go here (I'd assume not allowed). Since the array is already sorted you basically need to remove any strings that are exactly equal to the last one you've checked so keep track of that and compare. How you'd handle the array would depend on whether you're allowed to create a copy or you have to do it in place (i.e. in the same array).

Comment: Yes you’re right I did learn sets yet, and it’s allowed to create copy

Comment: Well in that case create an empty array of the same length, keep track of which index next to set and set that element if the current string is not a duplicate. You'll end up with an array that will contain a bunch of `null` elements at the end so to get rid of those just create another copy of the "non-duplicate" array that just contains as many elements as there are non-duplicate strings.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use sets, you can do it like this.  And it does not require a sorted array. It works as follows.  Note:  This changes the passed in array.

1. Get the first element.  If it is `null` continue to next element.
2. Compare first element to next.
3. If equal, replace next with a `null` and increment `removed`
4. Continue processing elements.

Now create a new array of original size minus - removed.
And copy all non null values to new array and return it.

```
    public static String[] removeDups(String[] arr) {
        // keep track of removed values
        int removed = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[i] == null) {
                // skip this entry and go to next
                    break;
                }
                if (arr[i].equals(arr[j])) {
                    // designate as removed
                    arr[j] = null;
                    removed++;
                }
            }
        }
        // copy remaining items to new array and return.
        String[] result = new String[arr.length-removed];
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length;  i++) {
            if (arr[i] != null) {
                result[k++] = arr[i];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

If you want to do it with streams you can do it this way.

```
String[] result = Arrays.stream(arr).distinct().toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you know that incoming array sorted, you can get current element and compare next elements with current one. If it is equals skip it, otherwise add this element to the result, and change current. Something like this

```
public static String[] dictionary(String s){
        String[] ans = sentence(s);
        if (ans == null || ans.length == 0) {
            return ans;
        }
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        String current = ans[0];
        result.add(current);
        for (int i= 1; i < ans.length; i++) {
            if (!ans[i].equals(current)) {
                result.add(ans[i]);
                current = ans[i];
            }
        }
        return result.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be to place them into a set

```
Set<String> setsHaveNoDuplicates = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(ans));
```

Sets have no duplicates, and if you want to convert the set back to an array of strings, you can do this

```
String[] result = setsHaveNoDuplicates.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: Do you have a way doing it with a for loop?

Comment: @davidkokiashvili  see my answer for the looped solution